# Distributed TensorFlow: many networks, one machine

Tags: python, tensorflow, architecture

I could successfully train neural networks in a distributed manner. The strategy I used was to replicate the graph on each of the workers.

For my current application, I need to define over 100 neural networks, each being trained asynchronously by all workers. I do not have the option of dispatching these 100 nets on the workers. Using the graph replication approach from before is not optimal, as it requires over 10Gb of RAM per worker.

Now what I'm trying to do, is to define for each worker a "local" variable which holds a copy of the "global" / shared variables.

I came up with this implementation: (`func` is called in a new process for each job)

```
def func(cluster, job_name, task_index):
    server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name, task_index)
    name = "/job:{}/task:{}".format(job_name, task_index)
    device = tf.train.replica_device_setter(worker_device=name, cluster=cluster)
    #########
    with tf.device(device), tf.variable_scope("global"):
        # Here I define the "global" variables. In that code snippet, I have one variable per network
        variables = [tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(BIG, ), dtype=tf.int32), name="variable{:05d}".format(i)) for i in range(N)]
    #########
    worker_0_device = tf.train.replica_device_setter(worker_device="/job:worker/task:0", cluster=cluster)
    with tf.device(worker_0_device), tf.variable_scope("local"):
        # Here I define one "local" variable per worker. They are placed on the parameter server.
        local_variable = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(BIG, ), dtype=tf.int32), name="worker{:02d}".format(task_index))
        # Here I define operations for downloading / uploading between "global" and "local" variables
        # Those operation are placed on the worker 0 (chief)
        local_variable_download = [local_variable.assign(gvar) for gvar in variables]
        local_variable_upload = [gvar.assign(local_variable) for gvar in variables]
    #########
    with tf.device(device), tf.variable_scope("local"):
        # Here I define the gradient computation / update of the local variable
        # Those operations are placed on the current worker (according to the parameters passed to this function)
        one = tf.gradients(local_variable, local_variable)[0]
        train = local_variable.assign_add(one)
    #########
    sess = tf.Session(target=server.target)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    #########
    if job_name == "ps":
        server.join()
    elif job_name == "worker":
        for a in range(10):
            for b in range(N):
                # Copy from ps0 to ps0 on device /job:worker/task:0
                download = sess.run(local_variable_download[b])[0]
                # Fake training on device /job:worker/task:n
                train_ = sess.run(train)[0]
                # Copy from ps0 to ps0 on device /job:worker/task:0
                upload = sess.run(local_variable_upload[b])[0]
                print("pass", a, "download:", download, "train:", train_, "upload:", upload)
    #########
```

There are two issues with that code:

- Some weight updates (train) are not taken into account. Sometimes two workers download the same global variables at the same time and the second upload overwrites the first one. I can think of ways of solving that, but I'm more concerned with the second issue for now.
- I still have the memory problem. It seems like the global variables are allocated in each thread.

There is something that I don't understand..

Help is much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running the process asynchronously, `celery/ redis` architecture you can follow for this, below are some useful documentation and installation links for that

```
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html
https://stackabuse.com/asynchronous-tasks-in-django-with-redis-and-celery/
```